# How to convert one-fold cross-validation to K-fold cross-validation in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I have a GAM model for which I would like to calculate AUC, TSS (True Skill Statistic) and RMSE through 5-fold cross-validation in R. Unfortunately, the *caret* package does not support GAM and therefore cannot be used. As I didn’t find any alternative, I tried to build the code for cross-validation myself, and it works well, with the only problem that it is only one-fold cross-validation. Could anybody help me to make this 5-fold? Sorry if this is an elementary question, I am new to R.

```
sample <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(DF), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.8,0.2))
train <- DF[sample, ]
test <- DF[!sample, ] 
predicted <- predict(GAM, test, type="response")

# Calculating RMSE
RMSE(test$Y, predicted)

# Calculating AUC
auc(test$Y, predicted)

GAM_TSS <- gam(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + s(X5, k = 3), train, family = "binomial")
test$pred <- predict(GAM_TSS, type="response", newdata=test)
roc.curve <- roc(test$Y, test$pred, ci=T)
plot(roc.curve)
threshold <- 0.1
CM <- confusionMatrix(factor(test$pred>threshold), factor(test$P_A==1), positive="TRUE")
CM <- CM$byClass
Sensitivity <- CM[['Sensitivity']]
Specificity <- CM[['Specificity']]

# Calculating TSS
TSS = Sensitivity + Specificity - 1
TSS
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across precisely this problem with GAM in the past. My approach was to create a vector to split data randomly into parts as equally sized as possible, then loop through the fold ids as follows:

```
k <- 5
FoldID <- rep(1:k, ceiling(nrow(modelData)/k))
length(FoldID) <- nrow(modelData)
FoldID <- sample(FoldID, replace = FALSE)
for(fold in 1:k){
  train_data <- modelData[FoldID != fold, ]
  val_data <- modelData[FoldID == fold, ]
 # Create training model and predictions
 # Calculate RMSE data etc.
 # Add a line with fold validation results to a dataframe
}
# Calculate column means of your validation results frame
```

I will leave you to fill in the gaps to suit your own requirements.  It would also be a good idea to add an outer loop (outside the FoldID creation) for repeats.